# Attaching pictures in storymap pop up

Tags: layers, attribute-table, arcgis-online, popup, story-map

I am working on a story map and for my layer I would like to have a picture for every single location to be shown on the pop-up. I have followed everything on this link: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm , but other than getting a picture icon in my pop-up, the picture doesn't show up.

I wonder if it is something I should change in my attribute table, like using an actual picture in my computer, or a picture on the web? or some data formatting I need to do in order to make this happen.

[image]

Comment: It could have something to do with the link to your pictures.  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do with your image link. If you're getting the link from a site that hosts photos be sure that you've set them to "public" or seen by "everyone". My tip is that check if your link usually ends with the format file of the photo (e.g. .jpg, .png, etc.)